# Android Play Store App Update

Tags: android

I lost my android apk certificate . Now i want to upload my new apk to the same application again, but its not letting me update and gives me a certificate error

is there a way to extract the certificate from it back ? i have the original apk if its possible using that

the app was build using adobe flash

please tell any details

You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1000000.
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
SHA1: 2C:AB:E2:C0:DC:F9:2C:C8:DE:1B:60:DE:84:A1:71:CA:B6:6D:70:8D
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
SHA1: CC:FF:DE:87:AC:5A:08:E5:ED:21:A6:52:1E:56:73:F1:CD:DF:7D:85

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have your old keystore then its possible otherwise not. You need to create new application with new package name for this and then you can upload. You must keep your keystore for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You're out of luck. How did you lose that certificate? Can't you do some hard disk recovery? Didn't you do a back up of it some place?

Comment: my hard disk crashed so i lost the certificate , is it not possible that my some tool i can recover the certificate from the apk?

Comment: No, otherwise anyone could do it and anyone could impersonate you as a developer and sign malware with it.

Comment: @VivekAgrawal Nope.  Not possible.  Your source code is backed up though?

Comment: depends on how your hard disk crashed. if its still working but you had to reinstall you OS you may want to hope that [one of the two tools linked in this forum can help you](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/255246-32-recover-files-format) otherwise there are also companies that can recover files but that would be expensive...